# Force Backbone fetch to always use POST

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Collection that needs to POST some data to its url to get the data it needs.  The answer to these two questions, [Fetch a collection using a POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428823/backbone-js-fetch-a-collection-using-post) and [Overriding fetch() method in backbone model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427086/overriding-fetch-method-in-backbone-model), make it seem like I should be able to get it to work like this:

```
fetch: function( options ) {
  this.constructor.__super__.fetch.apply(this, _.extend(options,{data: {whatever: 42}, type: 'POST'}));
}
```

, but Firebug still shows me a 404 error that is happening because a GET is being executed against the url in question (and the underlying Rails route only allows POST).  Should this be working?  If so, what else might I try?  If not, what have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you considered overriding Backbone's [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) or [`ajax`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-ajax) methods?

Comment: I would, if 1) I could figure out how, and 2) I could be convinced that overriding all of sync (which sounds hard and involved), was necessary because overriding fetch (which seems like it should be easy) has no chance of working.

Comment: Incidentally, the actual answer is that one of the posts I linked to didn't make it clear that the second argument to `apply` has to be an array.  D'oh.

Comment: Right, I missed that! I always get the [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) signatures mixed up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the least ugly way to force Backbone.sync updates to use POST instead of PUT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527694/what-is-the-least-ugly-way-to-force-backbone-sync-updates-to-use-post-instead-of)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After reading the question again, here's a way to force the fetch to use `POST` per fetch call. (Thanks for the comments)

```
yourCollection.fetch({
    data: $.param({id: 1234}), 
    type: 'POST', 
    success: function(d){
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

Another approach is to override the AJAX implementation itself to use `POST` for all calls.

```
Backbone.ajax = function() {
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    _.extend(args[0], { type: 'POST' });
    return Backbone.$.ajax.apply(Backbone.$, args);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't really answer my question about why what I had didn't work, but since this does...  thanks :-)

Comment: I just added another option on my answer to override all AJAX calls across the board.