# submitting AJAX using backbone models and collections

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I'm following [this](https://github.com/kjbekkelund/writings/blob/master/published/understanding-backbone.md) tutorial and trying to apply it in my simple login use case.

The simple jQuery ajax call is:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/element/User.php",
    data: {
        req: "REQUSERSIGNIN",
        platform: "WEB",
        useremail: $('form#userSignIn #userEmail').val(),
        userpass: $('form#userSignIn #userPassword').val()
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log("you've been logged in!"
    }
});
```

and of course this is called on:

```
$('form#userSignIn').submit();
```

My attempt at it using backbone is:

```
var events = _.clone(Backbone.Events);

var SigninModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: '/api/element/User.php'
});

    var SignInCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: SignInModel
    });

var SigninView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'submit form#userSignIn': 'signIn'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('Sign in view initialized');
    },

    signIn: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // How do I pass in the data as above?

    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    // What do I instantiate to make it all work?
});
```

How do I pass the data in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js fetch with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659283/backbone-js-fetch-with-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

To kick start the whole process you need to:

```
var view = new SigninView({
  model: new SignInModel(),
  el: $('#some-element')
}).render();
```

To explain more, $('some-element') will grab some existing html on the page, ie.

```
<div id="some-element"></div>
```

Then calling render() will render the view and attach the resulting html to your el(#some-element)

Notice, you need a render method. So in your view create a render function:

```
render: function() {
 var json = this.model.toJSON(); // JSON representation of your model data
 var html = this.template(json); // The html of your sign in view, probably consisting of
                                 // a form and some fields
 this.$el.html(html); // Attach the html to your cached jQuery el
```

You will also need a template attribute as part of your SignInView. To do this you use an 
[underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#template) template. In your SignInView:

```
template: _.template(//some html goes here)
```

Finally, you will need to grab the data from the form inputs

```
// ie. in your template you would have an input like this:
<input id="first-name" type="text" />
```

Then in your signInView,

```
var firstName = this.$('#first-name').val();
this.model.set('firstName', firstName);
this.model.save() // Calling save will delegate the AJAX call to Backbone            
                  // and send your data back as json
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I pass those "data:{}" parameters via ajax in order to get the response from the server in backbone?

Comment: You can use `fetch`. See this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15349949/force-backbone-fetch-to-always-use-post/15351548#15351548

Answer (score 0):

call toJSON() on your model

```
var data = {
  user: model.toJSON(),
  req: "REQUSERSIGNIN",
  platform: "WEB",
}
```

Then you can proceed as usual

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/element/User.php",
  data: data,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data) {
    console.log("you've been logged in!"
  }
});
```